# Why won't my app service clone properly on Azure

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I'm attempting to clone my web app using azure's clone feature. It's found under app services -> Developer tools -> clone app. Every time I run the function it results in a "Deployment Failed" due to conflict.

I've tried changing the clone options: target App name, using new and existing resource groups, new and existing app service plans and with or without application insights.

This is the error message I get every time I try to run this:

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/<My subscription>",
    "operationId": "<opID>",
    "properties": {
        "provisioningOperation": "Create",
        "provisioningState": "Failed",
        "timestamp": "2019-07-22T13:59:57.4502596Z",
        "duration": "PT3M32.7637096S",
        "trackingId": "<trackID>",
        "statusCode": "Conflict",
        "statusMessage": {
            "status": "Failed",
            "error": {
                "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
                "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "message": "Provisioning failed with errors: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.\r\n at System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError()\r\n at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)\r\n at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)\r\n at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GeoScale.Sql.WebSiteCloneManager.LogCloneProgress(Operation cloneOperation, SiteClone cloneRequest, CloneStatus cloneStatus, String messageFormat, Object[] args)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GeoScale.Sql.WebSiteCloneManager.AssociateClonedSiteWithSourceControl(SiteClone cloneRequest, Operation cloneOperation, GeoWebClient destinationStampClient, Site clonedSite)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GeoScale.Sql.WebSiteCloneManager.RefreshRestoreProgressForClone(IRepositoryContext context, SiteClone clone, Operation cloneOperation)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.GeoScale.Sql.WebSiteCloneManager.<>c__DisplayClass47_0.<ProcessClonesWithProvisioningInProgress>b__0(SiteClone clone)"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "targetResource": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<myresource>",
            "resourceType": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "resourceName": "<ResourceName>"
        }
    }
}
```

Update: The App was created but the deployment settings weren't transferred over. I'm using Kudu to deploy so that may have been what causes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your "update" on the question, if I understand correctly - 'The app was created but the settings weren't transferred over.'

Here are the known restrictions of app cloning currently (As mentioned in the Azure doc below):

- Auto scale settings are not cloned
  Backup schedule settings are not cloned
  VNET settings are not cloned
  App Insights are not automatically set up on the destination app
  Easy Auth settings are not cloned
  Kudu Extension are not cloned
  TiP rules are not cloned
  Database content is not cloned
  Outbound IP Addresses changes if cloning to a different scale unit
  Not available for Linux Apps

Reference Azure Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#current-restrictions

To clone an existing app including all associated deployment slots, you need to use the IncludeSourceWebAppSlots parameter. The following PowerShell command demonstrates the use of that parameter with the New-AzWebApp command:

$srcappslot = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName SourceAzureResourceGroup -Name source-app -Slot source-appslot

The following command demonstrates creating a clone of the source app to a new app:

$destapp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName DestinationAzureResourceGroup -Name dest-app -Location "North Central US" -AppServicePlan DestinationAppServicePlan -SourceWebApp $srcappslot

Additionally on Slots: 
When you clone configuration from another deployment slot, the cloned configuration is editable. Some configuration elements follow the content across a swap (not slot specific), whereas other configuration elements stay in the same slot after a swap (slot specific). The following lists show the settings that change when you swap slots.