# Azure Webapp Clone powershell script is not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I want to copy an existing webapp to another app plan. I have collected the command from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning

But getting **##[error]Long running operation failed with status 'InternalServerError'.** error when i am trying to run webapp cloning script.

Here is my script,

```
$srcapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName abcd -Name Testapp1

$destapp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName abcd -Name Testapp2 -Location "West Europe" -AppServicePlan appplan-1 -SourceWebApp $srcapp
```

Didn't find anything helpful on the web. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: Does $srcapp locate in "West Europe"?
Could you please also write the version of Powershell you are using?

Comment: Yes. Locations are both "West Europe" & I am using powershel version 5.1.22581.1

Comment: What is the version of your Azure Az PowerShell module?

Comment: Az PowerShell module version is 5.1.2

Comment: May you please try to Update you  Azure Az PowerShell module to latest version 7.4.0?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-7.4.0

Comment: Upgraded to the latest version 7.4.0 but the issue has not been solved..

Comment: That could be Azure related issue. Please create Azure Support ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried the same script that you are using based on the given [***`Microsoft Document`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#cloning-an-existing-app) in Question.

*The command you are trying ,which  can create the new app in the West Europe region, and tie it to an existing App Service Plan .*

***NOTE:- We are using an existing Appservice plan which is P1V2 with West Europe location.***

***Same error as you are getting:-***

[image]

***Tried to `az logout` & `az login` again and runned the script worked fine.***

***Also make sure that you have provided the App service file path as shown below.To get the path (APP SERVICE PLAN> PROPERTIES>RESOURCEID(COPY&USE)).***

```
$destapp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName RGNAME -Name appajtest13 -Location "West Europe" -AppServicePlan "subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourcegroups/my resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/existingappserviceplanname" -SourceWebApp $srcapp
```

***SUCCESFULLY CREATED OUTPUT DETAILS:-***

[image]

[image]

The PowerShell & az version which we are  using as shown below:

[image]
[image]

For more information you can refer this [***SO THREAD|Why won't my app service clone properly on Azure***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149290/why-wont-my-app-service-clone-properly-on-azure) as suggested by @***AjayKumar-MSFT***.