# Azure clone app via Powershell - InternalServerError

Tags: azure, powershell

I've been following this guide to cloning an existing app. I'm running the Az Powershell Module via Docker.

Here's what I ran:

```
$destapp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName HLP-API-NEW -Name hlp-api-new -Location "UK South" -AppServicePlan hlp-api-plan-new -SourceWebApp $srcapp
```

HLP-API-NEW is a new resource group that I created; hlp-api-plan-new is likewise a new service plan.

Here's how I got `$srcapp`:

```
$srcapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName HLP-API -Name api-hlp
```

The service plan / resource group nams are definitely correct. I get the following error:

> New-AzWebApp: Long running operation failed with stauts 'InternalServerError'

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your app is not under the below conditions. if it is in the below condition, we can't be able to clone it.

#### Restrictions to clone app

- Auto scale settings are not cloned
- Backup schedule settings are not cloned
- VNET settings are not cloned
- App Insights are not automatically set up on the destination app
- Easy Auth settings are not cloned
- Kudu Extension are not cloned
- TiP rules are not cloned
- Database content is not cloned
- Outbound IP Addresses changes if cloning to a different scale unit
- Not available for Linux Apps
- Managed Identities are not cloned
- Not available for Function Apps

If your app is not in the above criteria, you can clone it.

#### Ways follows

#### 1. Using Slot parameter

To clone an **existing app** including all associated deployment slots, you need to use the **Slots** parameter.

1. `$srcappslot = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group> -Name <Your app name> -Slot <slot name>`
2. `$destapp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group> -Name <Your new app name> -Location <location to create app> -AppServicePlan <App service plan name> -SourceWebApp $srcappslot`

#### 2. Using the new App Service plan

1. `$srcapp =  Get-AzWebApp  -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group> -Name <Your app name>`
2. `New-AzAppServicePlan  -Location  "Central US"  -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group> -Name <App Service plan Name> -Tier  Standard`
3. `$destapp =  New-AzWebApp  -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group> -Name <new app name to create> -Location  <Location to create app>  -AppServicePlan <Your new app service name> -SourceWebApp $srcapp`

#### 3. Using Existing App Service plan

1. `$srcapp =  Get-AzWebApp  -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group> -Name <Your app name>`
2. `$destapp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <Your Resource Group> -Name <new app name to create> -Location <Location to create app> -AppServicePlan <Specify exact App service file path (APP SERVICE PLAN> PROPERTIES>RESOURCEID)> -SourceWebApp $srcapp`

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand. You say I need to use the `Slot` parameter. But then under "Using existing app service plan" you don't specify that param. What exactly do I need to run to clone the app? Also, I don't know what format `APP SERVICE PLAN> PROPERTIES>RESOURCEID` should be in. What properties? And delimited now? What does a full filepath look like?

Comment: My bad I Updated the answer. The 3 ways we can achieve the cloning app. You can use any one of the approaches.

Comment: format `APP SERVICE PLAN> PROPERTIES>RESOURCEID` is follows `-AppServicePlan "subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourcegroups/my resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/existingappserviceplanname"`. you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71841678/15997690)

Comment: Sorry that I somehow missed your updates here. +1 and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I don't understand what's wrong with my command. While scouring the Internet I found this command which is leading me towards a solution. You may find it helpful as well:

```
PS> Resolve-AzError
```

This provided me the clue I needed to chase:

```
Message        : Long running operation failed with status 'InternalServerError'.
ServerMessage  : Restore failed with errors: Detail: Hostname 'abc.somedomain.com' conflicts with an already existing hostname.
                 ExtendedCode: 04005
```

Good luck!